# How to send a variable from JavaScript to a PHP script using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

For my project I need to do the following:

1. User presses his Mouse on the canvas (html page)
2. JavaScript function saves the coordinates of the points that have been pressed
3. Send this info to a PHP script
4. PHP script adds this data to MySQL database
5. Other coordinates are put into JSON and sent to back to the client and presented on the same canvas

Now, I have looked into the problem of step 3 (which is something I don't know how to do). There are different ways, I have selected these two:

1. [Using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955017/sending-json-to-php-using-ajax)
2. [HtmlRequest (answer 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Which would be the best way to choose in my situation? Is there yet a better / right way to do it?

Comment: you realize that ajax **IS** xmlhttprequest? that's like saying "use a ford F150" or "use a truck". they're the same thing.

Comment: jQuery allowed, I am not very proficient in it, but I will look into it. Will it satisfy my needs?

Comment: Marc, no I did not realize that, I thought that those were two different ways of sending info.  Probably I misunderstood the second link (post three), as the author there stated these methods to be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say there is necessarily a "right" way to do it, however there are some good ideas you can follow. One of those ideas is to use [HTTP REST verbs](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html): use `POST` for "create" operations and `GET` for "read" operations. Given that, you should do an AJAX `POST` request to your server and pass the coordinates via `POST` parameters.

```
// will use this to turn an object into a url encoded string
var serializeObject = function(obj) {
  var output = '';
  for(var attr in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(attr)) {
      output += attr + '=' + obj + '&';
    }
  }
  return output.slice(0, -1);
};
var url = 'http://www.example.com/save.php';
// you need to serialize your data into key value pairs like the following
var exampleCoords = {
  x: 10,
  y: 20,
  z: 30
};
// postData will be x=10&y=20&z=30
var postData = serializeObject(exampleCoords);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', url, true);
request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.setRequestHeader("Content-length", postData.length);
request.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

// this function gets called when the request changes
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // request was successful
    if(request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
}
request.send(postData);
```

Using jQuery you could simplify your code quite a bit (though it's pretty much doing the exact same thing behind the scenes):

```
var url = 'http://example.com/save.php';
var coords = {
   x: 10,
   y: 20,
   z: 30
};
$.post(url, coords).then(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
});
```

You can access those variables in PHP using `$_POST['x']`, make sure you sanitize this data ([`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), etc.) before using it in MySQL.

For the record, AJAX and `XMLHttpRequest` are different names for the same thing, AJAX is just referring to Asynchronous Javascript and XML (as in `XMLHttpRequest`), `XMLHttpRequest` is the built-in object you use to perform AJAX requests