# Turning PHP JSON string to valid json

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I have my form defined as follows in the PHP file :

```
<form id = "testForm" action="" method="post" >
    First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" value="Mickey"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="LastName" id="LastName" value="Mouse"><br>
    <button type = "button" onclick="submit()">Submit Top Test </button>
</form>
```

The following functions is called when the button is clicked.

```
function submit(){  
        var formdata = $("#testForm").serializeArray();
        var sendJson = JSON.stringify(formdata);

        var request = $.ajax({
                url: 'php/<path to php file>/processPost.php',
                type:'POST',
                data:{myData:sendJson},
                success: function(msg) {  
                     alert(msg);
                },
                 error: function(e){
                        alert("Error in Ajax "+e.message);
                 }

        });

    }
```

In `processPost.php` file, I have defined the following  :

```
1)  $json_obj = json_encode($_POST["myData"]);

2)  var_dump($json_obj);
```

To define the above PHP  stuff, I used the [answer posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955017/sending-json-to-php-using-ajax?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) by `Akhan Ismailov` with just a minor change(instead of `json_decode`, I am using 
`json_encode`)

I can see the following getting printed in the  `alert(msg)` window.

```
string(93) ""[{\"name\":\"FirstName\",\"value\":\"Mickey\"},{\"name\":\"LastName\",\"value\":\"Mouse\"}]""
```

I plan on making a curl request to my java webservice and I want to send JSON something like this :

```
[{
    "name": "FirstName",
    "value": "Mickey"
}, {
    "name": "LastName",
    "value": "Mouse"
}]
```

How can I get rid of `string(93)` and forward slashes `/` from the above code to make it a valid json first. Once, I have 
a valid json, I am planning on sending it as an object using cURL.

Comment: The `string(93)` is coming from `var_dump()` -- it's not actually in the JSON string.

Comment: `var sendJson = JSON.stringify(formdata);` this line is unnecessary. direct use  `data:formdata`, and then at php side print `$_POST` and see all data is coming or not

Comment: @AlivetoDie  Yes, that worked for me. When I just used `echo $_POST["myData"];`, I saw what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var sendJson = JSON.stringify(formdata);
```

This line is unnecessary.

direct use

```
data:formdata,
```

and then at `php` side print `$_POST` and see all data is coming or not

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST["myData"]` is already JSON so you don't have to do anything

```
$json =  $_POST["myData"];
call_my_web_service($json);
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST['myData']` is already JSON, since you used `JSON.stringify()` to create it. You need to use `json_decode()` to decode it, not `json_encode()`.

```
$obj = json_decode($_POST['myData'], true);
var_dump($obj);
```