# PHP AJAX JSON - Convert Input to JSON and Other PHP File Get The Value

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I noob and get mad when submit php form, convert input value to json, and other php file get it.

html

```html
<form action="submit.php" method="post" name="form1" id="myform">
  <table width="100%" border="0" style="font-size: 65px;">
   <tr> 
    <td>Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr> 
   <tr> 
    <td></td>
    <td><button id="submit">Submit</button></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
```

script.js

```
    $('#myform').submit(function (event) {
  name = $('#name').val();
  var data = {
    name: name
  }
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'submit.php',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      dataType: 'json'
    });
  return false
});
```

php file

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$name_dirty = json_decode($_POST['name']);
echo $name_dirty;
```

Can someone help me? submit.php got blank, I cant get the value that I submit from html page. Big Thanks

Comment: To help check your data, try changing `echo $name_dirty;` to `print_r($name_dirty);` this may help understand what is being passed to PHP.

Comment: If you make a simple search on SO you can find a lot of question and answer like this

Comment: I have search on SO but rarely the solution using json stringify

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Receive JSON POST with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php)

Comment: Question is .. why are you sending JSON ?? (cf https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955017/sending-json-to-php-using-ajax)

Comment: You don't need to use $_POST if you're passing a json string, use instead http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input

Answer (score 0):

Your Html

```
<table width="100%" border="0" style="font-size: 65px;">
        <tr> 
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td></td>
            <td><button id="submit">Submit</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

***Your JS***

```
  $('#submit').click(function() {
  name = $('#name').val()
  var data = {
    name: name
  }
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'submit.php',
      data: data 
      dataType: 'json'
            complete: function (resultData) {
            alert('data has been send')
    })
})
```

**In your php:**

```
<?php

print_r($_POST['data'])
```

A few notes. Make sure you check your paths. In my answer i assumed that the problem is in the code and not in wrong paths. Also when you use `form` tag you can use a submit button like   `<input type="submit" value="Submit">`  to submit your form without using Javascript.  It would work in your case but it's just another way to tackle your issue.

In my answer i removed your form tags and triggered the action on button click. There will be no redirect to the page but you can set a redirect inside the js if it is important to you, on success function of the ajax that i added. At the moment i just throw an alert message when it works successfully.